# Spring MVC JdbcTemplate : org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

I wanna use jdbctemplate with Spring MVC. But it shows following error in my spring configuration file:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] for bean with name 'jt' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] for bean with name 'jt' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean
```

I will share spring configuration file,pom.xml and my service class codes.Maybe it can be help us to find out problem.

**My spring configuration file :**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- Step 3: Add support for component scanning -->
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<context:component-scan base-package="rzaeeff.controller">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan>

<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@destinationip:1521/test" />
    <property name="username" value="BACK_UI" />
    <property name="password" value="pass" />
</bean>


<bean id="jt" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="dao" class="rzaeeff.services.impl.ObjectServiceImpl">
    <property name="template" ref="jt"></property>
</bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/gui/" />
```

**My service class :**

```
public class ObjectServiceImpl{

JdbcTemplate template;

public void setTemplate(JdbcTemplate template) {
    this.template = template;
}

public List<Object> selectAndSaveOld(int rowId) {

    final String QUERY_SQL = "SELECT * FROM TABLE";

    List<Object> dbLogList = this.template.query(QUERY_SQL, new RowMapper<Object>() {
        public Object mapRow(ResultSet resulSet, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

            Object dbLog = new Object();
            dbLog.setName(resulSet.getString("name"));
            dbLog.setSurname(resulSet.getString("surname"));

            return dbLog;
        }
    });
    return dbLogList;
}


public boolean editAndSaveNew(int rowId) {
    return true;
}
}
```

Maybe it's related with dependencies, versions or something else.

POM.XML file (dependencies)

[image: It;s my pom.xml .You can see all dependencies]

Comment: It seems you're missing [spring-jdbc](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc) dependency in your class path. Are you sure you have it properly defined?

Comment: I have added dependencies.But still same :

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Oracle jdbc driver-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: Show your pom please. You are missing something or having a conflict with versions.

Comment: I have added image which shows my pom.xml file

Comment: Next time add your pom as text, please. Change the spring-jdbc version from 3.2.0 to 4.1.6. Same you have for the rest of spring projects.

Comment: I have already test 4.1.6 but it's same (

Answer (score 0):

You are missing **spring-beans dependency**. If your packaging is war, check the lib folder if spring-beans jar is there. If its fat jar you are using, then either you can decompile and verify or you can use this maven dependency tree command to find out if the jar is included in classpath or not.

```
mvn dependency:tree
```